# pass AngularJS value / variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my Angular data (i write here only one data entry as demo, actually i have so many entry):

```
var font = angular.module('font', []);

font.controller('fontListCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.font = [
                     {
                        id: "_001",
                        name: "Kalpurush",
                        download: "1"
                      }
                ]

    var download = scope.font.download
});
```

I want to pass my download ID into inside javascript inside html. but i cannot success.

```
<div class="fontbox" ng-repeat="font in font">
{{font.name}}
<script>ccount_display('download')</script>
</div>
```

Please help me, thank you :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in this line -> `<script>ccount_display('download')</script>`? Are you trying to display something or is it a function? If it is a function, please add the relevant function code.

Comment: why do you have a script tag inside your div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making some assumption based on your code/question. If that's not the case, I can modify my solution.
There are couple of issues in your code. I've tried to fix them below:

```
var font = angular.module('font', []);
font.controller('fontListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fonts = [{
                    id: "_001",
                    name: "Kalpurush",
                    download: "1"
                  }];
     //assuming you're accessing above scope variable, your code had 'scope' but not $scope. And it's an array.
     $scope.download = $scope.fonts[0].download;
     //assuming you want to use download variable in your HTML.
});
```

Also the HTML is incorrect. You should do something like below:

ng-repeat="font in fonts"

Comment: in your HTML you were doing ng-repeat="font in font"... the names of both the variables were same.. so I changed this to   ng-repeat="font in fonts" and in the controller, the scope variable is now fonts.

Comment: Ok thank you sir. I am not professional. Now how can I bring this scope variable in ```<script>ccount_display('    in here   ')</script>``` ?

Comment: What is the intent here. Do you want to invoke a function on some button click ?

Comment: ccount_display is a download counter plugin, there i want to need specific id to show download count of specific item  like ```<script>ccount_display(' 1 ')</script>```

Comment: So for font with id "_001" is downloaded x times. and font with id "_002" was downloaded y times. And should this value be visible next to font name ?

Comment: Yes, sir. I can show it with by writing ```<script>ccount_display('1')</script>``` but inside ng-repeat how can i do it i cannot understand. At first i try ```<script>ccount_display('{{font.download}}')</script>``` but its don't work. Than I start trying with javascript "var"

Comment: if you want to pass the count to that function it should be like this ccount_display(font.download). But the next question is, how would you call this function ccount_display. It needs some event to fire, like a button click or mouse hover etc. Where would the user click to start the download ?

Comment: I dont write download link here. CCount is just a plugin based on php and javascript, it has no relation with this problem. I just need to bring font.download value inside ccount_display('here')

Comment: For that i already outlined the solution, font.download like this:    ccount_display(font.download)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem correctly you want to pass `id` into the `count_display` method you can do that by passing `font.id` and the use of the `<script>` tag in this context is not necessary. Hope this helps.